# call a function inside ngfor

Tags: angular, function, ionic2, ngfor

I'm quite new in angular2.

I have an ionic2 application and what I would like is to call a function inside an ngfor loop. The code I'm using is the following but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-mypage',
  templateUrl: 'mypage.html',
})
export class MyPage {

  itemlist = [
    {id:1, testf:"test1"},
    {id:2, testf:"test2"}
  ]; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MyPage');
  }


  myFunction(testf){

    console.log(testf);

    return testf;

  } 

}
```

and in html I have the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemlist">
  {{ myFunction(item.testf) }}
</div>
```

Although the output is printed twice as the number of item list, the function seems to be called multiple times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Binding to a method/function this way is usually a bad idea. The method is called every time change detection is run, which can be quite often. "every time change detection" is also the reason why it's called more often than you'd expect. Instead create an array containing the values and bind to the array items instead.

Comment: I'm quite new and I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to accomplish. You can use `<div *ngFor="let item of itemlist; let i=index">` to get the index of the current item. You can create an array with the same number of items as `itemlist` which contains the value that you want to show inside `{{}}` and then use `{{myArray[i]}}`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish @SymeonMattes ?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is a kind of validation test in a system, and each item in for loop is a validation test. So each loop should run a function that validates something. The way you're telling me it seems that if each validation test take e.g. 5min, then the output is going to be shown after 10min and not the first in 5, and the second in the  next 5 min etc.

Comment: And why not running these tests in the component code? You can use the first array to run the tests, and when you get a result, push that result to a new array. And then in the view, show the results array (everytime a new result is added to the array, it will be shown in the view)